# Selectively revoking access

Tags: google-oauth

Google now has Incremental Authorization similar to Facebook
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth

So one can incrementally authorize resources (Calendar/Contacts)
However while revoking access, there doesn't seem to be a way for user to remove access for selected resource (e.g. revoke access only for Calendar)

As per https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke, revoke removes access to all resources.

Is there a way to selectively revoke access? I see that Incremental Authorization support was added in Dec 2013. Is there a plan to support selective revoke ?

Answer (score 1):

At this point there is no way to revoke access to a subset of scopes.

If a user feels the need to revoke some scopes, the best is to revoke the whole application and then grant again limited scopes (if the user still trusts the application/developer). 
No comment on the plan.